# JQuery Mobile how to iterate through a list of elements and add their id's to a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a list of li tags in a unordered list. All the tags have a `class=listitem` and a `data-clicked=true/false` in them and I need to go through and write only the id's of the ones with `data-clicked=true` in them and add it to a string called `custidlist` and separate each item with commas. Here is what I have:

```
    $("#done").click(function() {
        var custidlist=""
        $(".listitem").each(function() {
        if ($(".listitem").data("clicked")==true) {
            custidlist=custidlist+$(".listitem").attr("id")+","
            alert(custidlist)
        }
    });
```

The alert is not showing up at all when the button is pressed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
$("#done").click(function() {
    var custidlist = $(".listitem").map(function() {
        return ($(this).data("clicked")) ? this.id : null;
    }).get();
    alert(custidlist.join());
});
```

Comment: @chrispytoes - It's *exactly* the same?

Comment: No wait, there's one difference, if will match any data-clicked attribute -> http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/3p6Gj/4/, not just `true`

Comment: For sure but will data-clicked ever be anything other than true, false or undefined? If so, then it's an issue, but I doubt it.

Comment: If @chrispytoes says it's working, it's probably not an issue, but it was the only difference I could find, using `$.map` or `.map().get()` is the exact same thing, and TwHello's answer works as well, so it's usually not very polite to accept the answer posted half an hour later than the others, but we can't all have good manners, so I don't care! Moving along!

Comment: @adeneo, building strings with successive `+=` leaves javascript's (generally) lazy GC with a lot more work to do. It's much better practice to build an array then glue the pieces together with `join()`. To me, that's a big difference.

Comment: Well, mine doesn't, it does exactly the same as this one, and all answers provide the same result. You're not the problem, if you want to answer and think you can, go for it, the issue is the OP accepting the last posted answer when there are two other answers that work just fine, but that happens all the time as well, and I really don't care. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

@adeneo has provided an elegant answer. This might help you see why your code didn't work.

```
$("#done").click(function() {
    var custidlist = "";
    $(".listitem").each(function() {
        if ($(this).attr("data-clicked") == "true")
            custidlist += this.id + ","
    });
    alert(custidlist)
});
```